# Trim string width jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, texttrimming

How can I trim the string width so that it is no longer than 20 characters including spaces and ... to the end of the string?

```
<p class="streetname">Galloway Road, Bishop's Stortford</p>
```

Is there a jQuery method for this?

Comment: Please add a reason for the down vote. I will try to fix the issue

Comment: Questions should include some indication of an attempt to resolve the issue (code that we can fix), or at least explain what research you've done, otherwise it's just *"write my code for me nao"*, which is not what Stack Overflow is for.  Note - I didn't downvote, but will if you don't make the question good :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` function on the string value of that paragraph text:

```js
var text = $('.streetname').text();
var newText = text.substr(0,17) + '...';
$('.streetname').text(newText)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="streetname">Galloway Road, Bishop's Stortford</p>
```

Comment: No idea why you got a down vote. Looks as if it works thanks

Comment: @Reece yeah. This should be a accepting answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
if ($(".streetname").text().length > 20) {         
    $(".streetname").text($(".streetname").text().substring(0,50) + '...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="streetname">This text is way to long to be displayed on the site so we just short it with jquery</p>
```

But if you recieve the text from php you can also short it there already..